# Create single Installer for all browser extension for all there browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, installation

I have already created extension toolbar for Chrome (.crx file), Mozilla Firefox (.xpi file), Internet Explorer (.exe file). Only thing that I need now to create a Single Installer (an EXE or MSI) for all three together.

Please, don't advise CrossRider; I don't know how to use it for already created third party extensions. I don't want to write the code again into CrossRider. If you know how to use my already written code, then it's OK; otherwise suggest something else.

You can also tell me how to use NSIS/ Inno Setup/ [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) to create Installer package for browser extension.

Comment: I can help you with Advanced Installer but I need more details about what would the install consists of. I assume you find the browsers installed using a registry search? Also, what is the location where you need to place your files? Do you compute it in a special way for each browser?

Comment: It would be great, If you could help me with advance installer. I have licensed Architect version of it. I have 3 files one is .XPI which is extension for Firefox, one is .CRX which is extension for Chrome, and the last one is .EXE extension for IE.. all are working Individually without any issue. I can install them manually.

Comment: You can take reference of following links for chrome and Firefox. for IE it's not going to be an issue as I have an exe to that I can call.

Comment: [Chrome Extension Installation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html)

Comment: [Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry)

Answer (score 6):

How can we do this with Inno Setup.

```
;Create Directory for Mozilla and Chrome

[Dirs]
Name: "{pf}\[Directory Name]"
Name: "{reg:HKLM\Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions,Path|{pf}\[Directory Name]}"
Name: "{reg:HKLM\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions,Path|{pf}\[Directory Name]}"

;Add Files

[Files]
Source: "Sample.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "sample@sample.com.xpi"; DestDir: "{pf}\[Directory Name]"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "phogkfodcfpcnalkmlcjmlnhgjacapcf\sample_chrome.crx"; DestDir: "{pf}\[Directory Name]"; Flags: ignoreversion

;Create Registry

[Registry]
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\mefpokegaaknljjamcdfhnimiiogmogk"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Path"; ValueData: "{pf}\[Directory Name]\sample_chrome.crx"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "Software\Google\Chrome\Extensions\mefpokegaaknljjamcdfhnimiiogmogk"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Version"; ValueData: "1.4"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "sample@sample.com"; ValueData: "{pf}\[Directory Name]\sample@sample.com.xpi"; Flags: uninsdeletekey

;Run Exe file

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you basically need to:
- detect the browser installed
- install the extension file in the desired path
- create registry entry

Solution proposal:
To detect the browsers you can create registry searches from [Search page](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/search.html). The search name is actually a public property, so you can use it to condition the install of your files and registry key, by setting a condition their corespondent components from [Organization page](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/organization.html).

Installing the files is easy, just go to [Files and Folders page](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/files-folders.html) and add them in the desired target folder. After this press F8 so you will be taken to the file component and set the install condition it.

The last part, is setting up the registry entries. Go to [Registry page](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/registry.html) and create them as you would in regedit. The same as for the files, after you create the entries for an extension go to its component using F8 and set the same install condition as for the files.

The uninstall is handled automatically when the package is removed from Control Panel, i.e. the files and registry entries created by the package will be removed.

Regarding IE, you can [call your EXE as a custom action](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-launch-batch-file.html). You will need two custom actions, ones that is executed on install, at the end of the installation to register the extension. The second custom action is to be executed on uninstall, in the beginning, so it unregisters the extension before the package removes the EXE.

Comment: Thank you very much Mitrache for all you effort, I have made it through Inno Setup.